# Apportable with Spritekit

Tags: android, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, apportable

I'm trying to port a project that uses SpriteKit and I'm having problem with these classes:

```
SKPhysicsBody

L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_63: error: undefined reference to 'OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPhysicsBody'

scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Does [Apportable](http://www.apportable.com/) supports SpriteKit?
What should I do?

Answer (score 8):

Apportable supports Sprite Kit. But at the time of writing (Feb 2014) it does not yet support physics. You'll have to refrain from referencing/using any SKPhysics* class for now.

**UPDATE** June 2014:

Apportable no longer supports Sprite Kit, current efforts are concentrated on improving cocos2d-iphone / cocos2d-swift and its "apportability".

Comment: I used this SpriteKit library new.So please explain in detail what should i do exactly.

Comment: simple: don't use physics or use custom physics (box2d, chipmunk) or ask Apportable what their ETA is regarding physics support

Comment: Seems like it's pretty hard for them to keep up... iOS 8 is coming out soon with new features for Spritekit. Should we still stick with spritekit and convert them using apportable?

Answer (score 2):

On 24th May 2014, apportable wrote on their forum that they have removed the partially implemented Sprite Kit:

> As of the 1.10.0 release, we have removed the partial implementation
>   of SpriteKit in our SDK. While we may add support in a future version
>   of the SDK, we are currently only supporting SpriteBuilder and the
>   Cocos2D game engine in the Starter and Indie versions of the SDK.

and that they recommend you use Cocos2D or contact them directly about a custom build:

http://forum.apportable.com/t/spritekit-in-developer-preview/252/7

http://forum.apportable.com/t/spritekit-in-developer-preview/252/5